# SwiftUIでNavigationBarの前面にViewを表示させたい

Tags: swiftui

NavigationBarの前面にViewを表示させたいです。
ZStackやoffsetを活用しても、どうしても背面に表示されてしまいます。
どなたか、分かる方がいらっしゃったら教えてください。

Comment: 普通に`ZStack`を使って、`NavigationView`と表示したいViewを重ねることで、NavigationBarの前面にViewが表示されました。現在のあなたのコードを含め、一体どう言った状況で何がしたいのかがよくわかるようにご質問内容を編集することは出来ませんか?

Comment: 前面に表示させたいViewにまでNavigationview をかぶせてました。初歩的なミスですいません。回答ありがとうございます！